# Errors in making zImage

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

The below is the error i'm getting while making a zImage..
Can anyone help me in this? Thanks

```
make: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
make[1]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-arm
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: arm-linux-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Comment: If using the option `V=1` with `make` it will log more details on what is trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the GNU arm tool chain i.e `arm-linux-gcc`

If you do not have it installed install Sourcery Codebench Lite. If you have binaries, set the `bin` directory path in PATH variable.You can do it by `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/arm/binaries/`